# What is the probability of three randomly(uniform) generated integers to be in sorted order(asc)?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I know that the answer to this question should be 1/6 if we consider any finite range $[-n,n]$( simply just $1/3!$). And in the limiting case, for any n it is $1/6$ .But let us consider generating the second number randomly, then generating the third and then the first one.  Probability of the third number being larger than the second is $1/2$( as we have no reason to distribute the probability otherwise), and similarly probability of the first number being smaller than the first is $1/2$(by same reasoning).So, the probability of them being in sorted order seems to be $1/2*1/2=1/4$. Consider my probability distribution as :
$P(X>=a)=P(X>a)=1/2$. Where do you think is the logical contradiction?

Comment: Why is the probability of the "third" number being larger than the "second" equal to $1/2$? You need to be more concrete about what exactly is the distribution you are generating numbers from.

Comment: In a finite range $(-n, n)$, once you have two numbers, can the probability of third being larger than the second be $1/2$? It can be smaller than first two, it can be in between them or it can be larger than the second.

Comment: For example, if you are generating random numbers uniformly from $1,\ldots, 10$, and you generate a $9$ for the "second" number, why is the probability of the "third" number being larger than the "second" equal to $1/2$?

Comment: in finite range it can't be ofc. But in infinite I can't see a reason why 1/2 wouldn't be the case?

Comment: You guys are considering the finite cases and then arguing for the infinite case. As I have mentioned, I know that in finite case the numbers don't behave like this. Just wanted to know why would you think that in infinite case 1/2 won't be the probability.

Comment: @Bhaswat There is no uniform distribution on all the integers, so it is unclear what distribution you are asking about.

Comment: I understand your point that in strict most sense, you can't get a uniform distribution over the natural numbers, as the sum of probability needs to be 1. So each of them will have zero probability. But again, zero probability doesn't mean they are impossible right? Let's just say we are picking integers completely at random with no integer getting special privileges over the others.

Comment: The problem is that you can't do that...

Comment: Why? could you please explain a bit? Kind of curious now.

Comment: Suppose $\mathbb P(X=n)=p$ for all integers $n$ (where $0<p<1$). Then $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} \mathbb P(X=n) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} p = +\infty, $$ which is clearly impossible for a probability distribution.